# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (GIORGI.RENT_FK_VIDEO) violated - parent key not found

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to recreate project
https://github.com/victorst79/PL-SQL-project/blob/master/Library.sql
when I try to insert into rent I get
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (RENT_FK_VIDEO) violated - parent key not found
OR
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (RENT_FK_BOOK) violated - parent key not found

```
CREATE TABLE rent (
    item_id      VARCHAR2(20),
    card_id      NUMBER,
    receive_date DATE,
    return_date  DATE,
    CONSTRAINT rent_pk PRIMARY KEY ( card_id,
                                     item_id)
);


CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id      VARCHAR2(20),
    isbn         VARCHAR2(10),
    title        VARCHAR2(100),
    state        VARCHAR2(10),
    availability VARCHAR2(1) CHECK ( ( availability = 'Y' )
                                     OR ( availability = 'N' ) ),
    rent_cost    NUMBER(5, 2),
    lost_cost    NUMBER(5, 2),
    address      VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT book_pk PRIMARY KEY ( book_id)
);


CREATE TABLE video (
    video_id     VARCHAR2(20),
    title        VARCHAR2(100),
    release_year INT,
    state        VARCHAR2(10),
    availability VARCHAR2(1) CHECK ( ( availability = 'Y' )
                                     OR ( availability = 'N' ) ),
    rent_cost    NUMBER(5, 2),
    lost_cost    NUMBER(5, 2),
    address      VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT video_pk PRIMARY KEY ( video_id)
);


ALTER TABLE Book
ADD CONSTRAINT Book_FK
FOREIGN KEY (address)
REFERENCES Location(address);

ALTER TABLE Video
ADD CONSTRAINT Video_FK
FOREIGN KEY (address)
REFERENCES Location(address);

ALTER TABLE Rent
ADD CONSTRAINT Rent_FK_Card
FOREIGN KEY (card_id)
REFERENCES Card(card_id);

ALTER TABLE Rent
ADD CONSTRAINT Rent_FK_Book
FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
REFERENCES Book(book_id);

ALTER TABLE Rent
ADD CONSTRAINT Rent_FK_Video
FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
REFERENCES Video(video_id);


INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1A123', 'A123', '', 'GOOD', 'Y', 5, 20, 'ARCHEOLOGY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B2A123', 'A123', '', 'NEW', 'N', 6, 30, 'ARCHEOLOGY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1B234', 'B234', '', 'NEW', 'Y', 2, 15, 'CHEMISTRY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1C321', 'C321', '', 'BAD', 'Y', 1, 10, 'PHYSICS ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1H123', 'H123', '', 'GOOD', 'Y', 3, 15, 'CHEMISTRY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1Z123', 'Z123', '', 'GOOD', 'N', 4, 20, 'COMPUTING ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1L321', 'L321', '', 'NEW', 'N', 4, 20, 'COMPUTING ROAD');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('B1P321', 'P321', '', 'USED', 'Y', 2, 12, 'CHEMISTRY ROAD');

INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1CH16', 'CHEMISTRY FOR DUMMIES', 2016, 'NEW', 'N', 10, 50, 'CHEMISTRY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V2CH16', 'CHEMISTRY FOR DUMMIES', 2016, 'BAD', 'Y', 5, 20, 'CHEMISTRY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1CO14', 'COMPUTING MANAGER', 2014, 'GOOD', 'Y', 4, 20, 'COMPUTING ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1JA15', 'JAVA LANGUAGE', 2015, 'USED', 'N', 4, 20, 'COMPUTING ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1DI00', 'DINOSAURS', 2000, 'GOOD', 'N', 5, 25, 'ARCHEOLOGY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1TR92', 'T-REX, DEADLY KING', 1992, 'USED', 'Y', 10, 50, 'ARCHEOLOGY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1AN98', 'ANCESTORS OF THE HUMANITY', 1998, 'BAD', 'Y', 3, 15, 'ARCHEOLOGY ROAD');
INSERT INTO Video VALUES ('V1PH18', 'PHYSICS, MOST BORING SH*T', 2018, 'NEW', 'Y', 1, 5, 'PHYSICS ROAD');

INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('B2A123', 101, '10-05-2018', '20-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('B1Z123', 102, '10-05-2018', '25-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('V1JA15', 104, '01-05-2018', '21-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('V1DI00', 105, '02-05-2018', '25-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('B1L321', 154, '04-05-2018', '26-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('V1CH16', 155, '29-04-2018', '29-05-2018')
```

item_id in RENT TABLE is FOREIGN KEY using book_id or video_id as part of primary key.
is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

These

```
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('V1JA15', 104, '01-05-2018', '21-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('V1DI00', 105, '02-05-2018', '25-05-2018');
INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('V1CH16', 155, '29-04-2018', '29-05-2018')
```

don't have parent key in `BOOK` table (i.e. you never inserted `VIJA15` into `BOOK`; the same goes for the rest of those keys, as well as the `VIDEO` table).

---

Furthermore, you're referencing tables `location` and `card` that don't exist (at least, not in script you posted).

---

Although not related to current problem, don't insert strings (such as `'01-05-2018'`) into `DATE` datatype columns. Insert

- date literal, e.g. `date '2018-05-01'` or
- use `to_date` function with appropriate format model, e.g. `to_date('2018-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: They have parent key in Video Table. that's what I'm trying to figure out. Is it possible for these values to be checked against either book or video table and return true if it is in either one of these tables? Otherwise how would one go about doing it? thanks for the recommendation about dates.

Comment: "Furthermore, you're referencing tables location and card that don't exist at least, not in script you posted."  --  They are working fine. I didn't include them in the code.

Comment: As of your 1st comment: if you inserted this: `INSERT INTO Book VALUES ('V1JA15', 'P321', '', 'USED', 'Y', 2, 12, 'CHEMISTRY ROAD');` then INSERT INTO RENT - which also insert V1JA15 - would succeed. Otherwise, it won't. That's the purpose of foreign key constraints; parent should exist before its child.

Comment: As of you 2nd comment: maybe they are working fine for you, but for us - who try to recreated that model - those foreign key constraints statements fail (because you didn't post CREATE TABLE).

Comment: Yes, it can work, but **only if parent keys exist**.

Comment: I mean can  Item_id in rent table Reference book_id from BOOK table OR video_id from VIDEO table at the same time and be correct if Item_id matches either of those cases? that is what I am trying to find out because source code had it like that. I also posted link for github where I found these codes and I'm simply trying to make analysis of the code. I'm not saying it should have worked for you in my 2nd comment.  if you need I can copy my entire code.

Comment: 'only if parent keys exist'  is what you said. if it exists in 1 table I get error for the other one and vice versa.  for example: B2A123 this exists in book table but when I try to  INSERT INTO Rent VALUES ('B2A123', 101, '10-05-2018', '20-05-2018');  I get error for video table.

Comment: It can; you'd then create two foreign key constraints - one that references BOOK.BOOK_ID and another that references VIDEO.VIDEO_ID. Note that the same key **must** exist in both tables; otherwise, at least one of those foreign key constraints will fail. If you have to do something like that, it *smells* like a bad data model.

Comment: That is what I posted I think.  Rent_FK_Book And Rent_FK_Video  So you are saying that same key must exist in both tables. that's what I was trying to find out.  how would you format these tables to avoid this problem?

Comment: Join books and videos into the same table. They share similar information anyway. Include additional master table (for the "type" (books or videos)) and include a foreign key to it into that newly created "books_videos" table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for fast and accurate responses